# What is the purpose of dropout layer in deploy.prototxt?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I read somewhere,  during testing there is no Dropout applied. What is the purpose of `dropout` layers in `deploy.prototxt`? Is not `deploy` file for testing the model? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI [Dropout: scaling the activation versus inverting the dropout](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/205932/12359)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714363/does-the-dropout-layer-need-to-be-defined-in-deploy-prototxt-in-caffe.

Answer (score 1):

A `"Dropout"` layer is used as a type of regularization by "switching off" responses at random during training: The layer will randomly set to zero `dropout_ratio` out of the inputs.
Depending on the way dropout is implemented, you might need to replace the probabilistic drop of the training by a scaling at test time. The test time dropout does this scaling for you.

Recent versions of caffe already "folds" this scaling into the training phase (see [`dropout_layer.cpp` line 41 and 59](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cpp#L41)), thus making this layer redundant during TEST phase.

Comment: Thank you very much Shai